# Неверно отображается TextView при сворачивании/разворачивании приложения

Tags: android

Всем здравствуйте. В общем, суть моей проблемы.
У меня простая программа-таймер: нажимаем кнопку "Запустить" - таймер тикает, нажимаем "Остановить" - таймер останавливается. Таймер отображается в формате `ЧЧ:ММ:СС` и работает нормально. Но когда я сворачиваю приложение и затем его снова разворачиваю - на таймере все по нулям. Смотрю логи - секунды, минуты и часы тикают, то есть с логикой программы все в порядке, вычисления я провожу в потоке `AsyncTask`. Я пришел к выводу, что проблема в отображении текущего времени. Как я это делаю:
Вот разметка xml-файла, секунды это `tvsecond`, минуты это `tvminute`, часы это `tvhour`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/back4">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/settings"
        android:id="@+id/btSettings"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:onClick="onClickSet"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_icon"

         />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="3" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
   >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvhour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:text="@string/hour"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/twoPoint"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvminute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/minute"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
<TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/twoPoint"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvsecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/second"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timePeriod"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:text="@string/timePeriod"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickGoStop"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btType"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickType"
        android:text="@string/record" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btShow"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickShow"
        android:text="@string/show" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    В главном классе я создаю TextView:

    TextView secTextView, minTextView, hourTextView;
    hourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvhour);
    minTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvminute);
    secTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvsecond);
```

Ну и потом в потоке `AsyncTask` с помощью метода `publishProgress()` присваиваю значения секунд текстовым полям. На версии `Android 2.3` все работает, на 4.0.4 при сворачивании/разворачивании приложения таймер сбрасывается в ноль.
Вывожу значения `hourTextView, minTextView и secTextView` в логи - все отображается правильно, почему же неправильно отображаются `tvhour, tvminute` и `tvsecond`?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка и куда копать? Может быть, это заморочка какой-то из версий?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего ты не указал в файле **AndroidManifest.xml** для активити **configChanges = "screenSize"**

А AsyncTask работает потому, что он работает в отдельном потоке и от рестарта активити никак не зависит

**UPDATE:**

Тогда советую вот эту [статейку](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana.html) прочитать. Да, там написано про поворот экрана. Да, ты не поворачиваешь экран, а сворачиваешь/разворачиваешь приложение. НО - теряется связь с Таском, как ее сохранить написано в статье.

Comment: Про AsyncTask разговора и не было - я уже выяснил, что проблема не в нем. Ваш метод не сработал.

Comment: обновил ответ